# Firefox reloads page even though I press "stay on this page" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am using window's **onbeforeunload** event to prevent user from leaving the page. Unfortunately, in firefox, if I press F5 to refresh the page repeatedly, and press "stay on this page" button every time, somehow firefox *reloads* the page eventually.

You can try to reproduce this bug on http://www.grooveshark.com

The most interesting thing is, that sometimes after this bug is reproduced you can see that there is no content loaded on the site (example: grooveshark.com). And now after refreshing the page again and again the content doesn't seem to load at all.

Please tell me if you've been able to reproduce this bug. Also I want to know if it is a known issue in firefox and how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    //IE & Firefox
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Your information has not been saved yet. If you leave now, the information might be lost.';
    }
    // For Safari
    return 'Your information has not been saved yet. If you leave now, the information might be lost.';
};
```

**P.S.**

Video: http://1drv.ms/1cICiSx

*And another thing.*

- Insert ANY code in jsfiddle :) Hold F5 button and press "stay on this page" repeatedly. Than release F5 and it'll update the page.

After reproducing the bug with this steps you can't input anything in jsfiddle input fields.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: you need to return false at the end of your function

Comment: Have you guys read the question? It works when you refresh the page once. And I can reproduce the bug not only on my site, but also on grooveshark.com

Comment: (And thats cause this is the only site that comes to my mind with this feature in use)

Comment: please reproduce on js fiddle, groove shark is not accessible :)

Comment: wow, my office provider has a DNS block for `www.grooveshark.com` ... must be a lovely link :D

Comment: yeah, you can find free music there :)

Comment: just a sec, I'll try jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, just insert ANY code in jsfiddle :) Hold F5 button and press "stay on this page" repeatedly. Than release F5 and it'll update the page.

Comment: All your code is perfectly lost, although you've been pressing "stay on this page".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/D2vTU/ your code running fine in fiddle

Comment: which browser version are you using

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yLR69/
The same thing with my code. Just F5 and "stay on this page" many many times until you see that page is reloading.

Comment: my browser doesn't allow any actions at the time of the prompt

Comment: Yes it is running fine, if you press the button once.

Comment: I am using Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: I cant press continuously iam using firefox 16. It's irresponsible, when i try to do multiple times

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll do a video for you :)

Comment: Ok, I haven't tryed it on firefox 16. We are talking about last version of firefox.

Comment: @Anto Vinish, I've added a video in the description.

Comment: @AntoVinish It's called "video" and it's swf file. Ok I think you'll find it.

Comment: I can reproduce when I press and hold F5, and click "Stay on page" repeatedly. I think it's a bug, so you should report it at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: @OllyHodgson thanks, I'll report it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug on bugzilla.mozilla.org and it got confirmed. So now it's a known issue. Here is a link to the bug.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=981574